# With Bootstrap CSS prev and next arrows centrally aligned either side of a container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How in Twitter bootstrap css can I get  prev and next arrows aligned centrally around either side of a container  e.g. similar to carousel navigation ?

```
<div class="text-center" > 
    <a href="#!/details/{{prevItem}}" class="btn btn-left-primary">&lt;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
    <a href="#!/details/{{nextItem}}" class="btn btn-right-primary">&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;</a> 
</div>
```

these prev and next buttons are aligned next to each other I need them to sit centrally around a box

```
<section class="detailsinfo" > 
    <div class="pull-right">
        <a href="#!/details/{{nextItem}}" class="btn btn-right-primary">&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;</a>
    </div> 
    <div class="row vertical-align"> 
        <div class="pull-left"> 
            <a href="#!/details/{{prevItem}}" class="btn btn-left-primary">&lt;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

class row -vertical align appears to sort out the left button but not the right

Comment: Can you add some code please?

Comment: There is lots of ways to stop things being centre aligned but it depends on the code. could be as simple as padding or margin

Comment: <div class="text-center" >


        <a href="#!/details/{{prevItem}}" class="btn btn-left-primary">&lt;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>

        <a href="#!/details/{{nextItem}}" class="btn btn-right-primary">&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;</a>
</div>

Comment: these prev and next buttons are aligned next to each other  I need them to sit centrally around a box

Comment: <section class="detailsinfo" >
        <div class="pull-right">

        <a  href="#!/details/{{nextItem}}" class="btn btn-right-primary">&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>

        <div class="row vertical-align">
            <div class="pull-left">

                <a href="#!/details/{{prevItem}}" class="btn btn-left-primary">&lt;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>

Comment: class row -vertical align appears to sort out the left button but not the right

Comment: Please update your question with your code, don't just put them in the comments.